# read iframe content from chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to load iframe.html inside an iframe and append that iframe to the DOM of the current page from my chrome extension. I have done so and I am able to handle click events, get the frame element values(input,select box). Everything is fine till here. Now the problem is I couldn't modify the content inside the iframe.html once I have inserted it into the DOM(To be more specific, I have a input box in iframe.html[which is appended to the DOM] with value as "XXXX" and now I want to change it to "YYYY" when user clicks on context menu of my extension).

I tried to get the input box value by using

```
$('#iframe_id').contents().find('input#input_id').val('YYYY')
(or)
window.frames['iframe_id'].document.getElementId('input_id').value
```

in my content.js but of no help.

```
console.log($('#iframe_id'))
```

prints the iframe Object in the console but unable to get the iframe document content. Is this the right way to get/modify the iframe content inserted by a chrome extension? or am I missing something here from chrome.* APIs

Any pointers on how to resolve this would be more helpful.

TIA,
Jagadeesh

Comment: Why use an iframe? It seems to complicate your solution based on te given information.

Comment: What would you suggest me to do? Some pointers on this

Comment: What is the content that you are trying to pull in the iframe? Maybe you can get the data in another way. Dealing with iframes is always a pain.

Comment: I have some input fields. I need to read the values and modify it when user clicks on context menu of my extension.

Comment: If that's the case, I'm confused why you need to use an iFrame. Why not just insert the html into the page you want it in?

Comment: I can do that and that would work fine. But I have some styles which I want them to be overwrite the iframe html. If I don't use iframe and instead just append html page styles would overwrite mine(meaning for e.g I would insert this html to google.com ang gmail.com then styles of google and gmail may overwrite mine rite?)

Comment: Yes. You'll have to do a little bit more work to get the styling to work how you want but I believe it to be the better approach in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike Grace mentioned, I have inserted html instead of iframe and constructed the css such that it would work in any of the web pages. This would be a better approach in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are having problems because the domains and protocols of the iframe and top-level page don't match. This is a page security restriction. If this does describe your problem you can workaround the restriction by using the iframe postMessage API.

Comment: I don't think this should be a problem with chrome extensions as I already have taken cross-origin permissions in manifest.json file. More here http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html